# Firefox' string break behavior in other browsers?

Tags: html, css, firefox, break

I have a long string without spaces, but with slashes, that I want to display in a table-cell.

Firefox adds breaks before the slashes at the end of a line. Other browsers only break the string if I add

```
td {    
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

to my CSS.

**Firefox:**

[image: screenshot firefox]

**Chrome**

[image: screenshot chrome]

**Chrome with word-break**

[image: screenshot chrome with word-break]

Is there any CSS-property to get the firefox behavior in Chrome, etc.?

You can find a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/rM9Dx/2/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

Hi now you can used **this** `word-wrap:break-word;`

as like this

**Css**

```
  div {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.wrap{
    word-wrap:break-word;
  width:200px;
  border:solid 3px green;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>description:<td>
        <td><div  class="wrap">431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K431121251K
          </div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Live demo  http://tinkerbin.com/6uNnlfow

more info http://www.css3.info/preview/word-wrap/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case `word-wrap:break-word` does exactly the same as `word-break:break-all`. I need linebreaks before or after the `/`-characters